# Is the spectral theorem for operators or matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

A is a normal operator if $A A^* = A^* A$. This means for any matrix $M$ representing $A$, we have $MM^* = M^*M$. Let $M$ be one such matrix, and $P$ be an invertible but non-unitary matrix.

Then $N=PMP^{-1}$ is the matrix for the same operator wrt a different basis. But now it seems to me it is no longer true that $NN^* = N^*N$. I expand the two sides and get

$$N N^* = P M P^{-1} P^{-1*} M^* P^*$$

which is not the same as

$$N^* N = P^{-1*}M^*P^*PMP^{-1}$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If $A$ is a linear operator in a inner product space $V$, and $M$ is a matrix that represents $A$ with respect to some basis $\beta$ for $V$, then $M^*$ is the matrix that represents $A^*$ with respect to $\beta$ **only if** $\beta$ is orthonormal.

Comment: All this means is that the notion of a normal operator is inextricably bound to what inner product you're using.  With $P$ non-unitary, the inner product with respect to the different basis is not the standard inner product.

Comment: @azif00 Ah yes, I forgot about that! Thanks to both of you for your comments. Now I'm wondering how to mark this as answered...

Comment: @Partha It can only be marked as answered if an "answer" (as opposed to a comment) is posted. If you like, you could post a quick answer and "accept" it.